# Why the exception is not caught in this multithread example?

Tags: java, multithreading, exception, parallel-processing

I was trying to learn how exception propagate in multithread.

**Question**

In the following example.
Why is the `RuntimeException` exception not caught in

```
`System.out.println("Exception handled " + e);
```

**Given Code**

```java
package p05_Interrupt;

public class D05_Interrupt1 extends Thread {
  public void run()  {
    try {
      Thread.sleep(1000);
      System.out.println("task");
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      throw new RuntimeException("Thread interrupted..." + e);
    }
  }

  public static void main(String args[]) {
    D05_Interrupt1 t1 = new D05_Interrupt1();
    t1.start();
    try {
      t1.interrupt();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println("Exception handled " + e); // Why not print this line 
    }
  }
}
```

[1st example in JavaTpoint "Example of interrupting a thread that stops working"](https://www.javatpoint.com/interrupting-a-thread)

**Output**

```
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.RuntimeException: Thread interrupted...java.lang.InterruptedException: sleep interrupted
    at p05_Interrupt.D05_Interrupt1.run(D05_Interrupt1.java:9)
```

---

Is that because this is multithreading, so exception is printed in the thread `t1`, and the output of `main()` thread is hidden?

I also tried to add throws at `public void run() throws RuntimeException {` didn't change anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot catch (like that) the exception thrown by the Thread in the *main* thread. However, you can implement [Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler.html) to achieve that.

> **public static interface Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler Interface** for
> handlers invoked when a Thread abruptly terminates due to an uncaught
> exception.
>
> **When a thread is about to terminate due to an uncaught exception the
> Java Virtual Machine will query the thread for its
> UncaughtExceptionHandler using Thread.getUncaughtExceptionHandler()
> and will invoke the handler's uncaughtException method, passing the
> thread and the exception as arguments.** If a thread has not had its
> UncaughtExceptionHandler explicitly set, then its ThreadGroup object
> acts as its UncaughtExceptionHandler. If the ThreadGroup object has no
> special requirements for dealing with the exception, it can forward
> the invocation to the default uncaught exception handler.

```
public class D05_Interrupt1 extends Thread 
        implements Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler {

    public void run() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            System.out.println("task");
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Thread interrupted..." + e);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        D05_Interrupt1 t1 = new D05_Interrupt1();
        Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(t1);
        t1.start();
        t1.interrupt();
    }

    @Override
    public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) {
        System.out.println("Exception handled " + e); // Why not print this line
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Exception handled java.lang.RuntimeException: Thread interrupted...java.lang.InterruptedException: sleep interrupted
```